# How to apply profanity filter

Tags: string-manipulation, filtering, linguistics

What is the simplest way to filter out profanity from Word Data without manually removing the words?

Comment: There is a build-in and ready to use classifier function for recognizing profanity in text. If you give a example of how you would like to use `WordData` I will write up an more specific answer to that if you like.

Comment: Functions like `TextCases` and `TextPosition` can also recognize profanity.

Comment: You'll make several  clbuttic mistakes if you try.    And then you'll either delete "prick my finger" or fail to delete "finger my prick"  .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9629371/3170791):

```
newWordData = Complement[WordData[], Import["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/LDNOOBW/List-of-Dirty-Naughty-Obscene-and-Otherwise-Bad-Words/master/en", "List"]];
```

Comment: Whoever compiled this list has been watching too much fetish porn. There are many extremely uncommon words/phrases in there, most of them not really classifiable as "profanity". It's more like a list of search terms to be avoided.

Comment: @OleksandrR. Pssh, obviously the likes of "xx", "butt", "twinkie", "mr hands" and many other phrases that without context are totally harmless should be outright **banned** from human language **entirely**

Comment: At [alabama hot pocket](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=alabama%20hot%20pocket) I grew suspicious and by the time I scrolled down the list of excluded words to [cleveland steamer](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Cleveland+Steamer) I knew the author basically crawled all of Urban Dictionary and just took the result as words to filter out.

Comment: @Sascha, that, or the curator is/was a /b/ habitué.

Answer (score 11):

As an example I take the following list of words

```
testdata = WordData[All, "Verb"] // Select[#, StringContainsQ[#, "fu"] &] &
```

> {"befuddle", "be full", "bifurcate", "blow a fuse", "centrifugate", 
>   "centrifuge", "circumfuse", "coiffure", "confuse", "confute", 
>   "defuse", "desulfurize", "diffuse", "effuse", "fuck", "fuck off", 
>   "fuck up", "fuddle", "fudge", "fudge together", "fuel", "fulfill", 
>   "fulfill", "full", "fullback", "fulminate", "fumble", "fume", 
>   "fumigate", "function", "fund", "fund-raise", "fund raise", 
>   "fundraise", "funk", "funnel", "furbish", "furbish up", "furcate", 
>   "furl", "furlough", "furnish", "furrow", "further", "fuse", 
>   "fusillade", "fuss", "fustigate", "get a noseful", "give full 
>   measure", "infuriate", "infuscate", "infuse", "make full", "make 
>   fun", "malfunction", "misfunction", "obfuscate", "perfume", 
>   "perfuse", "poke fun", "refuel", "refund", "refurbish", "refurnish", 
>   "refuse", "refute", "snafu", "suffuse", "sulfur", "sulfurette", 
>   "transfuse", "travel purposefully", "trifurcate", "ultracentrifuge", 
>   "unfurl"}

and use the build-in classifier function `"Profanity"` to obfuscate bad language (you could just filter out words too)

```
Clear@profanityFilter
profanityFilter[word_] := StringReplace[word, {_ :> 
RandomChoice[{"&", "#", "!", "%", "@", "$", "^", "%", "*"}]}] 
/; Classify[ "Profanity", word]

profanityFilter[word_] := word
```

Now you can apply the filter to individual words or map it to a list of words to make your language squeaky clean:)

```
profanityFilter /@ testdata
```

> {"befuddle", "be full", "bifurcate", "blow a fuse", "centrifugate", 
>   "centrifuge", "circumfuse", "coiffure", "confuse", "confute", 
>   "defuse", "desulfurize", "diffuse", "effuse", "%*!^", "&%#^&^%!", 
>   "%!!%!%!", "fuddle", "fudge", "fudge together", "fuel", "fulfil", 
>   "fulfill", "full", "fullback", "fulminate", "fumble", "fume", 
>   "fumigate", "function", "fund", "fund-raise", "fund raise", 
>   "fundraise", "funk", "funnel", "furbish", "furbish up", "furcate", 
>   "furl", "furlough", "furnish", "furrow", "further", "fuse", 
>   "fusillade", "fuss", "fustigate", "get a noseful", "give full 
>   measure", "infuriate", "infuscate", "infuse", "make full", "make 
>   fun", "malfunction", "misfunction", "obfuscate", "perfume", 
>   "perfuse", "poke fun", "refuel", "refund", "refurbish", "refurnish", 
>   "refuse", "refute", "snafu", "suffuse", "sulfur", "sulfurette", 
>   "transfuse", "travel purposefully", "trifurcate", "ultracentrifuge", 
>   "unfurl"}

Comment: To identify "fuck off" in its own right rather than because it contains "fuck" would be impressive. It makes me wonder, does this pass the ["Scunthorpe test"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem)?

Comment: @OleksandrR. one could probably build some classifier that takes into account not only the literal meaning of a word but also the actual meaning via something like `WordData["fuck off"]` which gives you {{"fuck off", "Verb", "Excite"}, {"fuck off", "Verb", 
  "GoAway"}, {"fuck off", "Verb", "Slug"}}. Together with some syntactic analysis to figure out the context one could use that additional information to discern whether the user intended it as profanity or not.